# Why do my recent sms show elapsed time instead of time sent or received? Pixel 3 android 11

Tags: sms

Why do my recent sms show elapsed time instead of time sent or received? ie:"10 min ago" instead of 10:27pm.
Pixel 3 android 11

Comment: This depends on the Messaging app you're using. Since this is Pixel 3, is this the default Google Messages app?

Comment: Yes, default app 'messages'